# After using pyinstaller to make my python exe file I got the error - "Failed to excecute script pyiboot01_bootstrap

Tags: python, exe, pyinstaller, py2exe

I am trying to make a python file into a exe file, but unsuccessfully.

After trying some long code, I tried also one line script - `file = open("b.txt")` and it also wasn't worked .

I do it this way -

```
pyinstaller myscript.pyw -F

cd dist

myscript.exe
```

Can u help me?

Its always write - "Failed to excecute script pyiboot01_bootstrap"

It's also write after it - Failed to excecute Myscript

Comment: Run PyInstaller like this: `pyinstaller --log-level=DEBUG -F myscript.pyw`, edit your question and paste the output.

Comment: Your errors mean something like your PyInstaller environment is corrupted. Try a virtualenv and install PyInstaller again and check if you still get the above error. Also, I suggest you add a minimal version of your code for better help.